# Math.random to never generate same number as other Math.random

Tags: javascript

I got 4 Math.random generators. Each picking 1 of the X objects from the array.

```
  var randomItem1 = projects[Math.floor(Math.random()*projects.length)];
  var randomItem2 = projects[Math.floor(Math.random()*projects.length)];
  var randomItem3 = projects[Math.floor(Math.random()*projects.length)];
  var randomItem4 = projects[Math.floor(Math.random()*projects.length)];
```

How can I write a function that prevents the Math.random to generate the same number as other Math.random generator.

*My guess:
Creating a loop that loops through the `var randomItem 1 till 4`. If it finds 1 or more outputs to be the same, it will regenerate a new output for 1 or more the duplicated outputs.*

Any other suggestions?

Edit: This is for a website.

Comment: Shuffle the array (or an array of indices) and pick 4.

Comment: or take a set and check against.

Comment: Once you pick something, remove it from the array.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the interesting problem. I always used a library for this sort of thing so it was fun figuring it out.

```js
var projects
var randomProjects

function getRandomProjects(projects, sampleSize) {
  var projectsClone = projects.slice();
  var randomItems = [];
  while (sampleSize--) {
    randomItems.push(
      projectsClone.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*projectsClone.length), 1)[0]
    );
  }
  return randomItems;
}

projects = ['1st project', '2nd project', '3rd project', '4th project', '5th project', '6th project'];
randomProjects = getRandomProjects(projects, 4);

randomProjects.forEach(function(randomProject) {
  console.log(randomProject);
});
```

The `projectsClone.splice(...)` deletes a random project from `projectsClone` and returns it as a single item in an array (`[<project>]`). Thus in the next iteration of the loop that value (`<project>`) can no longer be chosen.

However I would suggest using a library if you are using this in production code. For example [losdash's `_.sampleSize(projects, 4)`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#sampleSize)

Answer (score 1):

## Update

Removed unneeded parts like <del>`Set`, `for` loop</del>, and added `splice()`. This function will mutate the original array due to `splice()`. Using `splice()` on an array of consecutive ordered numbers (even after shuffling) guarantees a set of unique numbers.

---

```
/**
 * genRan(quantity, length)
 *
 * Need a given amount of unique random numbers.
 *
 * Given a number for how many random numbers are to be returned (@quantity) and a 
 * number that represents the range of consecutive numbers to extract the random 
 * numbers from (@length), this function will:
 *  - generate a full array of numbers with the length of @length
 *  - use shuffle() to shuffle the array to provide an array of randomly ordered numbers 
 *  - splices the first @quantity numbers of the shuffled array
 *  - returns new array of unique random numbers
 *
 * @param {Number} quantity      length of returned array.
 * @param {Number} length        length of an array of numbers. 
 * 
 * @return {Array} An array of unique random numbers.
 */
```

---

### Demo

**Details commented in Demo**

```js
var qty = 4
var len = 100;

function genRan(quantity, length) {
  // Ensure that quantity is never greater than length
  if (quantity > length) {
    quantity = length;
  }
  // Create an array of consecutive numbers from 1 to N
  var array = Array.from({
    length: length
  }, (value, key = 0) => key + 1);
  // Run shuffle get the returned shuffled array
  var shuffled = shuffle(array);
  // return an array of N (quantity) random numbers 
  return shuffled.splice(0, quantity);
}

console.log(genRan(qty, len));

/* shuffle utility 
|| Uses Fisher-Yates algorithm
*/
function shuffle(array) {
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  var temp = null;
  for (i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i -= 1) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
    temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}
```